# Post Arabic text to MySQL from Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, arabic

This is my code for uploading text to PHP file and then to MySQL server:

```
  List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", title));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", text));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", currentDate()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photoid", photoId()));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", latit));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", longi));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_UPLOAD,
                "POST", params);
```

The code from the `EditText` is in Arabic language so it works and in MySQL. I can add Arabic language, it works. I tried to add from PHP to MySQL manually and it worked.

So, it seems the problem is that the text is not received well in the PHP file from the Android application.

In MySQL it is stored like `?????`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add (N) Character before the string You send to query As

> N'ننن'

and everything will be ok

Good Luck

Comment: for text should I do like : text = "N'"+text+"'"; or what do you mean ?

Comment: Can you explain more. I have tried that already, It didn't seem to work

Comment: I mean as @stangabogdan said "for text should I do like : text = "N'"+text+"'"; "

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to post all the parameters in JSOn format, in this case you dont have to worry about text encoding. use GSON to serialize all params into JsonObject then post as part of body